# Using MySQL LIMIT in query after using FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm kinda new on this one, and I'm building my first website. Just for fun and to learn how everything works.

I have this weird issue, I can't figure out how to do it:

```
$query = "SELECT * from artikel inner join categorie on artikel.artikelnummer = categorie.artikelnummer
inner join categorienaam on categorie.categorienummer = categorienaam.categorienummer
left join bestandsnaam on artikel.artikelnummer = bestandsnaam.artikelnummer
where categorie.categorienummer = ".filter_var($_GET['categorienummer'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT)." LIMIT $first_product_shown, $products_per_page";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    do stuff
}
```

It works when I'm not using the LIMIT. But I don't know how to get this limit to work. For example, this one works:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM artikel LEFT JOIN bestandsnaam ON artikel.artikelnummer = bestandsnaam.artikelnummer LIMIT $first_product_shown, $products_per_page");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    do stuff
}
```

I think my code fails because of the combined use of 'FILTER_SANITIZED_NUMBER_INT' and 'LIMIT'. Maybe anyone knows what the problem is? I need this to get my products on my website splitted into pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it is just an `int` why not just cast it as such? If not echo out the query and see what it is sending to the db..

Comment: `echo $query;` so you can see what the filtering generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is failing because you appear to be missing the query call in the first code block. Try echoing out the mysqli error

In your second block you have called the SQL inside the query directly, but not in the first and have not added the query.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Stupid of me! Guess it was time to go to bed ;).

Comment: No problem kenny, if this answers your question please press the tick to accept the answer.

Comment: I already tried to vote up, but since I made my own account 2 dags ago, I can't vote up. I need 15 reputation before I can do that. But yes, it answered my question :).